# OneDrive Incorrectly Tags .xlsm as Virus

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA-rich xlsm file that OneDrive has now marked as having a virus. I created the file six months ago and have worked with it a good deal recently without issues. One of its features is that it creates a daughter file that contains user preferences for the file itself (its used throughout our company). I think that OneDrive has perhaps recently been devised to spot this activity and tag the subject file as a virus. Anyone else have this problem and if so, how did you get around it? I am looking into the possibility of having it digitally signed, but I understand that it's not a fun process and any changes mean going through the process again. Thanks for any help anyone can provide here.

Mark

Comment: What *exactly* does this tagging look like?

Comment: OneDrive does have alternatives...

Comment: This an enterprise situation, so no alternatives. As to how it looks, I think the OneDrive icon in the computer's menu bar showed a symbol of some kind. When the OneDrive window was launched, it had a yellow-shaded message at the top saying the subject file had a virus and would not be saved to OneDrive. It must have tagged the file in some hidden way too, as I couldn't email it to myself at home nor to anyone else.

Comment: MS apparently solved this issue, as it went away soon after I posted this question.